# Highcharts : Venn Diagram to show the total of union numbers?

Tags: highcharts, venn-diagram

I am using highchart.js to generate reports. I need to generate venn diagram like the below.

[image]

The above Venn Diagram shows the sets with their values and the intersection of sets. I wanted to get the total of each set with it's intersection value (e.g 445 + 138 = 583). I didn't any working example.... any help to achieve the above requirement.

Answer (score 1):

To create a basic Highcharts VENN diagram with the overlap you show as an example you would have to do something like this ([JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mwpn6a2y/)):

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'venn',
        dataLabels: {
          formatter: function () {
            return this.point.value;
        }
      },
        data: [{
            sets: ['A'],
            value:583
        }, {
            sets: ['B'],
            value: 231
        }, {
            sets: ['A', 'B'],
            value: 138,
        }]
    }],
    tooltip: false,
    title: false
});
```

The elements missing from this, compared to the values shown in your example, are the value that each "slice" has, e.g. 445 and 93.

The following example shows how to use each points sets to subtract values from overlapping points to get the value of the slice. Here "S" represents the slice value (e.g. 445 and 93) while "V" represents the value of the full circle (e.g. 583 and 231):

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'venn',
        dataLabels: {
          formatter: function () {
          const value = this.point.value;
          const slice = this.series.points.reduce((p, a) => {
            if(a === this.point) {
              return p;
            }
            else if(this.point.sets.every(s => a.sets.includes(s))) {
              return p - a.value;
            }
            return p;
          }, value);
          
          if(value === slice) {
            return `V/S: ${value}`;
          }
          else {
            return `S: ${slice} | V: ${value}`;
          }
        }
      },
        data: [{
            sets: ['A'],
            value:583
        }, {
            sets: ['B'],
            value: 231
        }, {
            sets: ['A', 'B'],
            value: 138,
                  name: 'C'
        }]
    }],
    tooltip: false,
    title: {
        text: 'Showing name, value (V) and slice value (S)'
    }
});
```

See [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/pa31jmLc/). It does not solve the placement of the text itself, but provides the requested values.

This code will not work in all cases, particularly if you have multiple points that overlap the same segment, then you may end up subtracting too much. You would have to adjust the formatter to adjust for this problem, presented in [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/92co58t7/1/).

Comment: As an addition to the answer above, I would like to add that you can use Highcharts.SVG Renderer which allows you to render any svg including text https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer